Limit post authors on my WordPress site to only seeing, editing and deleting what they create
I created this code so that each wordpress user with the "Author" rule can see, create, edit and delete only posts by them, in general it is working, but the post counters at the top of the list continue to display posts by all other authors on the site.
function my_modify_author_capabilities( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    $edit_capabilities = array( 'edit_post', 'delete_post', 'read_post' );

    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        foreach ( $edit_capabilities as $edit_cap ) {
            if ( $cap === $edit_cap && isset( $args[0] ) ) {
                $post = get_post( $args[0] );
                if ( $post && $user_id !== $post->post_author ) {
                    $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $caps;
}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'my_modify_author_capabilities', 10, 4 );

function my_remove_other_users_posts_from_author( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && ! current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
        global $pagenow;

        if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
            $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_remove_other_users_posts_from_author' );

function my_adjust_post_counts( $counts, $type, $perm ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
        global $user_ID;

        // Only adjust counts for 'post' post type
        if ( 'post' === $type ) {
            $cache_key = _count_posts_cache_key( 'post', '' );
            $cache = wp_cache_get( $cache_key, 'counts' );

            if ( false === $cache ) {
                $counts = array_fill_keys( get_post_stati(), 0 );

                $statuses = get_post_stati( array( 'show_in_admin_status_list' => true ), 'names' );
                $avail_post_stati = get_available_post_statuses( 'post' );

                $count = $wpdb->get_results(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                        "
                        SELECT post_status, COUNT( * ) AS num_posts
                        FROM {$wpdb->posts}
                        WHERE post_type = %s
                        AND post_author = %d
                        GROUP BY post_status
                        ",
                        'post',
                        $user_ID
                    ),
                    ARRAY_A
                );

                foreach ( $count as $row ) {
                    if ( in_array( $row['post_status'], $avail_post_stati ) ) {
                        $counts[ $row['post_status'] ] = $row['num_posts'];
                    }
                }

                wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $counts, 'counts' );
            } else {
                $counts = $cache;
            }
        }
    }
    return $counts;
}
add_filter( 'wp_count_posts', 'my_adjust_post_counts', 10, 3 );

example image
I want users to only be able to see the content that was published by them, and the counters to also only show what was authored by them.

I found a solution, now Wordpress has a feature called private posts, just activate it and everything works. :D
